# Miniconda - Importing from python file in another folder

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins-pipeline, miniconda

We execute python scripts in jenkins pipeline within miniconda virtual environment. The structure of the folders that is copied with python scripts to workspace looks like:

```
main_folder
    /pyscripts1
        /script11.py
        /script12.py
    /pyscripts2
        /script211.py
        /script22.py
    /pyscripts3
        /script31.py
        /script32.py
    /utils
        /utils1.py
        /utils2.py
```

What is the best way to import `utils` script into scripts in `pyscripts` folders?

I would normally use something like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/libs/')
```

but I cannot use absolute path in this case. From what I know conda does not use `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: `conda does not use PYTHONPATH` - `conda`(the package manager) does not use `PYTHONPATH`. If you start `python` however, the `PYTHONPATH` is used just as you would expect

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is the code that helped me through:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/..")
```